# Why won't my code take the input from the command line?

Tags: java, command-line, integer, reverse, digit

The point of this program is to take a three digit number from the command line and then reversing it. After that it is supposed to subtract the reverse from the original number and add the original to the reversed.

This is supposed to only take numbers that are three digits and the first digit of the number has to be greater than the last so that it is not negative when the numbers are subtracted.

The code compiles correctly but when I put a number in the command line prints out the line "Enter a three digit number, with the first digit larger than the third" only.

What it is supposed to print out like

```
$ java Rev 351
Reverse and subtract: 
 351
 153 - 
 ---
 198

Reverse and add:
 198
 891 + 
 ---
1089
```

This is my code:

```
public class Rev
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a three digit number, with the first digit larger than the third");
            num = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            reverseNum(num);
            subtractNum(num);
            addNum(num);
        }

    }

    static boolean checkDigits(int number) // checks if numbers are correct
    {
        int reverse = reverseNum(number);

        if(number > reverse)
        {
            throw new Error("Reverse number needs to be less than the original number!");
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    static int reverseNum(int number) //reverses number
    {
        int reverse = 0;

        int r = 0;

        while (number != 0)
        {
            if(number < 1000 || number > 99)
            {

            r = number % 10;

            reverse = (reverse*10) + r;

            number = number/10;
            }
        }

        return reverse;
    }

    static void subtractNum(int number) // subtracts
    {
        int reverse = reverseNum(number);

        int total = number - reverse;

        System.out.println("Reverse and subtract: ");
        System.out.println(number);
        System.out.println(reverse + " - ");
        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println(total);
        System.out.println();

        number = total;
    }

    static void addNum(int number) // adds
    {
        int reverse = reverseNum(number);

        int total = number + reverse;

        System.out.println("Reverse and add: ");
        System.out.println(number);
        System.out.println(reverse + " + ");
        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println(total);

        number = total;
    }

}
```

Comment: how are you running this ?

Comment: he means, what is the command line you use to run this code when you are testing it

Comment: it would also help if you printed out what your desired output for that command line would be

Comment: I put it above the code of what it is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a three digit number, with the first digit larger than the third");
            num = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            reverseNum(num);
            subtractNum(num);
            addNum(num);
        }

    }
```

So the `args` variable is the command line argument. So if you're compiling via command line, you would call something like `java Rev.class 321` where `321` is your 3 digit number. If you want to use the Java console to take inputs, use a `Scanner`.

To take inputs, use something like this:

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 num = sc.nextInt();
```

Comment: This just prints out the the line "Enter a three digit number, with the first digit larger than the third," when I put a number in the command line.

Comment: You should let it run, and when it prints the line, then enter your input

Comment: I put an example of how it is supposed to print

Comment: No, the printing makes sense. What we're trying to figure out is how you want to do `command line arguments`. By command line do you mean the terminal when you execute the .class file? Or do you mean in the Java console in an IDE like Eclipse?

Comment: Ok. So then you cannot prompt the user to enter, because you're running it in the terminal. So, I assume you're running something like `java Rev.class 321` where 321 is your number? There's no way to prompt before you're actually executing your program.

Comment: What do I need to change so that I can do that?

Comment: Use a `Scanner` to ask for user arguments. The code won't continue to execute until the user types something and presses `Enter`

Comment: Okay so I got it to work on the command line but only when numbers are put in. When I just put java Rev it is supposed to print "Enter only a three digit number, with the first digit larger than the third" but it is coming up with an error

Comment: That is because the numbers that you put in are in the `args` array. If it is empty, your code attempts to access the `args` array and can't because it is empty. So, basically don't use `args` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're never actually getting a number from the input. You need to do this in your `main()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a three digit number, with the first digit larger than the third");
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)){
            num = s.nextInt();
        }
        reverseNum(num);
        subtractNum(num);
        addNum(num);
    }

}
```

The `Scanner` reads the main input stream (from the keyboard). Otherwise, when you pass in the argument on the command line, it hasn't yet asked you for the input, and prints out the request for input.

Your other problem is that you don't call checkDigits() after getting your number, so you should probably do a while loop using it until you get a number you'll accept, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int num = -1;
    while (num < 0 || !checkDigits(num)){
        System.out.println("Enter a three digit number, with the first digit larger than the third");
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)){
            num = s.nextInt();
        }
    }
    reverseNum(num);
    subtractNum(num);
    addNum(num);

}
```

Also, your other methods are incorrect in that they are acting on an input parameter (which is possible for objects but not primitives, and is bad practice in any case).

Instead write them as functions which take in values and return them, then modify your main again to look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    if (checkDigits(num)){
        num = subtractNum(num);
        addNum(num);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Enter only a three digit number, with the first digit larger than the third");
    }
}
```

Comment: Now when I enter a number all it prints is "Enter a three digit number, with the first digit larger than the third." But that is only supposed to print if no number is inputed. And when no number inputed that statement does not show up

Comment: I need to use the command line to get the input though. That is a requirement. Even with your second fix it still does not work.

Comment: Is there something wrong with my other methods that I am not seeing?

Comment: You can't "get" input from the command line after your program starts, so the line "asking" for input is flawed. Command-line arguments are entered when you call your program; ie `java -jar myprogram.jar 321`

Comment: The program is supposed to take a three digit number and only a three digit number. It can't take one or five digit numbers. It can't have totals come out to negative numbers either. If nothing is put in the command line then that one that is the only thing printing now, is supposed to print

Comment: I put an example of what it looks like in the command line and then how it is supposed to print

Comment: I've edited this answer with an extra point. Your subtractNum() function isn't properly returning its answer. It should be `static int subtractNum()`, not `static void subtractNum()`, and should return its result rather than acting on the input parameter.

Comment: Yes, so put one in. Change the last line from `number = total;` to `return total;`

Comment: Now when I run it nothing prints after I type java Rev 321

Comment: Still does not change with the return statement

Comment: Your reversing algorithm is incorrect. You will know it is correct when your final answer = 1089.

Comment: I just realized that. What needs to be changed?

Comment: It is in my addNum() that is the issue. How do I change that?

Comment: Okay but there is still a problem. When I don't put in a number and just do java Rev it is supposed to say "Enter a three digit number, with the first digit larger than the third" but now it is coming up with an error

Comment: You need to check to make sure your input is not null or an empty string before you give it to `Integer.parseInt(arg[0]);`